Используя функцию connect из react-redux не передаются пропсы в компонент
Вот весь код, отвечающий за логинизацию на сайте
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form"
import { withElement } from "../common/FormsControl/FormsControls"
import { requiredField } from "../../utils/validators/validators"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { loginThunk} from "../Redux/auth-reducer"

const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const InputElem = withElement('input')
    const {handleSubmit} = props
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <div><Field name="email" component={InputElem} validate={requiredField} placeholder="Email"/></div>
            <div><Field type="password" name="password" component={InputElem} validate={requiredField} placeholder="Password"/></div>
            <div><Field name="remember" component={InputElem} type="checkbox" />Remember me</div>
            <div><button>Login</button></div>
        </form>
    )
}


const ReduxLoginForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'login'
})(LoginForm)


export const Login = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const onSubmit = (formData) => {
        props.loginThunk(formData.email, formData.password, formData.remember)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <ReduxLoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
        </div>
    )
}




export default connect(null, {loginThunk})(Login)

Подскажите почему в пропсах в компоненте Login нет ничего?
